# how to combine the Universal selector and Attribute selectors in CSS

Tags: css

I need to meet this demand：Write your page so that if you hover over any element (i.e. any header, paragraph, image, etc), the element is highlighted in yellow.This must be a one-selector, one-property addition to your stylesheet -- no commas allowed! (Note: This is tricky.)

As the demand,this is tricky! Hope you can help me,THX~

Comment: I have try this:   *:hover {color:yellow} ,but all the element is yellow but one

Comment: The title of the question does not match the text of the question at all. Only a comment tells what you have actually tried, and it does not actually say how it fails. (*Which* element is not yellow?) The description does not say what “highlighting” means, e.g. how you are supposed to highlight an image.

Answer (score 1):

i have used `z-index` and `pseudo` element `:after`

here is the js fiddle

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7k0v0x8/1/)

```css
    * {
        position:Relative;
        background: transparent;
        z-index:1;
    }
    *:hover:not(html):not(body):after {
        content:" ";
        background: yellow;
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:-1;
    }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</div>

<h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p></h1>
```

Comment: this solution is weird but it works http://jsfiddle.net/b7k0v0x8/3/  i have added `:not(div)` which acts as a `container` containing all the elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for  this

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
      $('*').mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).css('background','yellow');
      }).mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).css('background','#fff')  
      });
 });
```

Comment: The biggest problem is that I can not us javascript